# Adding DLL as a reference to my SharpSSH C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-assembly, sharpssh

I have downloaded `SharpSSH` Binaries [from the link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpssh/files/SharpSSH/1.1.1.13/SharpSSH-1.1.1.13.bin.zip/download). When i extracted it i found 3 `.DLL` files (and also a `EXE` file).

1.) DiffieHellman.dll
2.) Org.Mentalis.Security.dll
3.) Tamir.SharpSSH.dll

I need to add these as `Referece` to the project. I need to know which one of these `.DLL` files i need to add as `Reference` to the project.

And also can you let me know how i should add `References` to my C# project.

Note: what i want to do is to upload, download file from a `FTP` site through `SFTP` connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a reference you your project, right click and select `Add Reference` and navigate to the respective dll(s).

Comment: Which files should i add ? all 3 or ?

Comment: Well if it doesn't say which ones specifically in the documentation, I would put all three references. Once you get everything implemented, you'll know if you can remove any of the three.

Comment: @Illep you only need to reference `Tamir.SharpSSH.dll`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a fairly old question but we still use the SharpSSH library and the only dll you need to reference is `Tamir.SharpSSH.dll`, the other 2 dll's will automatically be included.